# How can I prove `false` and by extension anything from Coq hypothesis 'd=d+1'?

Tags: coq

```
Goal forall (d : nat), d + 1 = d -> False.
Proof.
  intros d H.
Abort.
```

How can I prove `False` from `H`? `inversion H` is just replicating it.

Comment: You could try induction (and then inversion). You could also just run omega :P

Comment: @abhishek Please provide [MCVE] in your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can discover some helpful lemmas to do derive a contradiction from your context. First of all we need to import a module containing them, otherwise the `Search` command won't be able to discover those lemmas:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
```

Let's check if we have exactly the lemma we need (recall that `x <> y` is a notation for `not (eq x y)`, and `not A` stands for `A -> False`):

```
Search (?x + _ <> ?x).
```

No luck this time. Ok, addition is commutative, let's trying it this way:

```
Search (_ + ?x <> ?x).
```

Nothing again. But we certainly should have something like that:

```
Search (S ?x <> ?x).
```

Finally we have the following lemma:

```
Nat.neq_succ_diag_l: forall n : nat, S n <> n
```

which we can use like so:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Goal forall (d : nat), d + 1 = d -> False.
Proof.
  intros d H.
  rewrite Nat.add_comm in H.
  now apply Nat.neq_succ_diag_l in H.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The proof follows by induction on `d` and uses:

```
eq_add_S
     : forall n m : nat, S n = S m -> n = m
```

The base case is `0 = 1` which by inversion leads to `False`, this concluding the case. The inductive case you have `d + 1 = d -> False` as the induction hypothesis and `S d + 1 = S d -> False` as your goal. We know that `x + 1 = y + 1 -> x +  y` from `eq_add_S`, so we rewrite our goal and apply the induction hypothesis.

Complete proof:

```
Goal forall (d : nat), d + 1 = d -> False.
Proof.
  induction d.
  intros.
  - inversion H.
  - intros H.
    erewrite <- eq_add_S in H; eauto.
Qed.
```